# Springboot 2 RSocket application starts then stops immediately with no error message

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket

I just pick a springboot application sample with RSocket starter : [image]
Building, then running the runnable jar gives me the following logs :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2019-12-04 09:45:20.985  INFO 12928 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on XXX with PID 1234 (demo/target/classes started by me in ~/demo)
2019-12-04 09:45:20.987  INFO 12928 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-04 09:45:21.761  INFO 12928 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.172 seconds (JVM running for 2.378)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The problem is the Springboot main thread stops immediately without waiting RSocket requests.
I guess the problem is the RSocket server is not started so I tried to add a RSocket controller like this :

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @MessageMapping("retreiveSomeData")
    public Mono<Data> retreiveAccount(String criteria) {
        return Mono.just(new Data());
    }

}
```

Same result^^

Anyone using RSocket with SpringBoot find a "beautiful" way to force Springboot thread to wait ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add an RSocket Configuration.

Just add the following `application.yaml` :

```
# application.yaml
spring:
  rsocket:
    server:
      port: 7000
```

Then the Netty server will be started on port 7000 :

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

INFO 4472 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication       : Starting DemoApplication on ...
INFO 4472 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
INFO 4472 --- [           main] o.s.b.rsocket.netty.NettyRSocketServer   : Netty RSocket started on port(s): 7000
INFO 4472 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication       : Started DemoApplication in 2.704 seconds (JVM running for 3.142)
```